# Как создать динамический массив объектов для индексатора в С#?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. У меня создано два класса, один - шаблон для объекта, а второй - индексатор, хранящий ссылки на массив объектов первого класса. Я хочу сделать массив динамическим, чтобы при создании или удалении объекта размерность массива изменялась, и работать можно было бы с любым количеством объектов. Но вышло у меня только создать статический. Объясните доходчиво, как создать динамический массив для моих целей. Класс с массивом прилагается ниже.

```
public class HomeLibrary
{
    private Book[] BookArr;
    public HomeLibrary(int size)
    {
        BookArr = new Book[size];
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return BookArr.Length; }
    }

    public Book this[int pos]
    {
        get
        {
            if (pos >= BookArr.Length || pos < 0)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            else return (Book)BookArr[pos];
        }
        set
        {
            BookArr[pos] = (Book)value;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: List<T> вместо массива использовать

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать 'Generic.Collections.List'.

```
List<Book> lists = new List<Book>();
```

хочешь сам можешь реализовать алгоритм динамического массива.

```
   public class MyList
   {
       private int[] _data;
       private int _stateCount;

    public MyList()
    {
        _data = new int[10];
        _stateCount = 0;      

    }

    public int this[int pos]
    {
        get
        {
            if (pos >= this._data.Length)
                throw new Exception();
            return this._data[pos];
        }
        set
        {
            this.Update(value, pos);
        }
    }


    private void initializeDynamic(int Lenght = 10)
    {
        int[] old = new int[_data.Length + Lenght];
        Array.Copy(_data, old, _data.Length);
        this._data = null;
        this._data = old;
    }

    private void Update(int Item,int Index)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Index < 0 || Index >= this._data.Length)
                throw new Exception();
            this._data[Index] = Item;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
    }

    public void Add(int Item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_stateCount >= (this._data.Length - 1))
                initializeDynamic();
            this._data[_stateCount] = Item;
            _stateCount++;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
    }

}
```